# compare two audio files. sound match

Tags: java, php, javascript, actionscript-3, audio

I want to start a big project and it is required to compare two audio files to get % of match.

Example :

1. audio A is the original audio.
2. audo B is recorded from microphone. ( everything is same as in audio A, except for voice )
3. I want to know how close B is to A in percents. ( 100% = identical )

Does anyone know a way how to do this?

*Maybe it could be possible by comparing spectrum of file A with the spectrum of file B..*

Comment: It all depends on what do you mean by "comparing two audio files". 100% is easy to imagine but how about 0%?. As you can see, the definition of "comparison of audio files" is not well defined so your solution will be not define as well. Should the comparison be computed on a perception point of view (sounds which resemble the same on both audio files) or should it be based on a mere byte-byte arithmetic difference?

Comment: You might write a book on sound processing and comparison, so voted to close as 'overly broad'.

Comment: What does compare mean for you? You have to check the vocal and the instrumental. May this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673042/algorithm-to-remove-vocal-from-sound-track

Comment: You have posted this question with four programming language tags.  Pick *one* and you might actually be able to get some useful help.  I can preemptively say that PHP has virtually no audio processing libraries, so you should look elsewhere.

Comment: hey did you ever end up figuring this out? looking for the same thing

Answer (score 2):

I have done this sort of thing in my undergrad course project but with image files. The thing you would want to look into is [Cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). In which you can measure similarities between two signals. Also you might want to preprocess the audio files ie: normalize, apply some low pass filter to remove noise.

I would suggest Digital Signal Processing by Oppenheim to get a deep understanding of signal processing.

But again these techniques are quite vague, until yopu know what type of similarities you want to find.

Comment: To follow up on image comparing, there is a company (LTU) that has an application for comparing images based on a vector and then the vectors are compared, this reflects the difference between 2 images. This is not a byte/byte comparison, it matches cropped and inverted images. Maybe their technique can be adapted to audio files. That said, I doubt you can get your hand on their algo.

Comment: @Nick.T But, I think there has to be some open source projects to do these things.

Comment: I only know of it because a client said to me "I want LTU". So no research of opensource projects for me. I do agree that this type of algo must exist in an opensource project. Maybe the question could be rephrased and asked in the `mathematica` stack...

Comment: Yes and also like as @charles said, the question should be with tag like matlab.